# Non commutative Teichmuller theory

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, banach-algebras, teichmuller-theory

Perhaps the first example in   Teichmuller theory is the following proposition:

**Proposition:** Let $1<r<R$. Then two annular region $U_r=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\bigm|1<|z|<r\}$  and  $U_R=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\bigm|1<|z|<R\}$ are not bio holomorphic.

We consider the following two Banach algebras:

$A_r=\{ f:\overline{U_r}\to \mathbb{C}\bigm|f\quad \text{is continuous and is holomorphic in the interior of this closed annular region}\}$

$A_R=\{ f:\overline{U_R}\to \mathbb{C}\bigm|f\quad \text{is continuous and is holomorphic in the interior of this closed annular region}\}$

Are these two complex Banach algebeas isomorphic algebras?

**Note:** In the literature are there some researchs which apply operator algebraic methods for consideration of some problems in Teichmuller theory?

Comment: An interesting question, but are you sure it has to do anything with noncommutativity?

Comment: The spectrum of $A_r$ is $\overline{U_r}$, isn't it? Hence any isomorphism gives rise to a homeomorphism, which must be holomorphic.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA is right: I suspect something like this result must be mentioned in one of the classical books on function algebras, such as Gamelin's book on Uniform Algebras, or maybe Stout's book. This is Gelfand theory for Banach algebras and has nothing to do with "noncommutative geometry"

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA  I am familiar with the Gelfand theory. so every isomorphism gives a homemorphism between maximal ideak spaces. But what is the reason this homeomorphisms must be holomorphic in the interior?

Comment: @YemonChoi  In the references you mentioned, can I find  t answer to my previous comment?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Thank you for your kind words about this question. I think it is a terminology "Noncommutativization" which is coined for consideration of classical problems with methods from operator algebras, banach algebras, etc.I frequently  heared the statement for example "What is the analogue statement in the non commutative world". I choose the title of this question based on this literature.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA  I would appreciate if you ellaborate your comments. Could you please write an answer? Can one generalize this to higher dimensional bounded open set in higher dimension. In higher dimension we holomorphic rigidity.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA   can one introduce These annular allgebras in the form of universal algebras(with some relations)? may be a hidden parameter $q$ in this possible representation could give us a non commutative annular region?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Perhaps my previous comment can explain the reason of "Non commutative " terminology.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA  I know that an isomorphism between algebras gives us a homeomorphism between maximal ideal space wrspc to  weak topology on the unit ball of the dual space. but I do not know the reason for holomorphicity

Comment: @YemonChoi  Are annular algebras mentioned in the books you introduced?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I was trained in Banach algebras to solve problems using the given definitions rather than being shown details of where the results could be found, so I cannot offer detailed advice on the literature. The answer to your question comes from knowing how the homeomorphism is defined in terms of the given isomorphism of Banach algebras

Comment: I can give a quick explanation as an answer, but I would prefer that you change the title of this question to remove references to operator algebras and "noncommutative mathematics". The trend you refer to as *"I think it is a terminology "Noncommutativization" which is coined for consideration of classical problems with methods from operator algebras, banach algebras"* is in my opinion NOT a good one, it makes one's work seem like empty addition of buzzwords, especially when your particular question concerns **commutative** Banach algebras

Comment: If you have a more general question concerning noncommutative algebras which could provide some analogue of complex function theory or Teichmueller theory, then you could post that as a separate question. My point is that the particular question you asked has an easy answer which is nothing to do with "noncommutative X"

Comment: @YemonChoi thank you for introducing me these two references. I had already learned Gelfand duality from Rudin book. However a colleagues introduced me the gamelin books, but I did not happened to browse it. I try to find the answer to this question(and its generalization, non commutative perturbation etc) by reading these two books and other references. After all what would be a universal algebraic introducing of these annular algebras? Are there some reference investigating some properties of these algebras?